# How to use bidders like appnexus, pubmatic when the prebid adapter is called?

Tags: adapter, server-side, prebid, header-bidding

I am planning to build a new adapter in prebid.org. I am using smartAdserver to manage my campaigns so I am planning to build a new adapter using smart.
I am doing this as publishers who are using Pubmatic open wrap or similar models and other Ad networks are now asking for a prebid adapter.
I already have client side header bidding wherein I bid with multiple bidders like YahooSSP, Sharethrough, Pubmatic etc.
My question is how should I use the existing bidders like YahooSSP, Pubmatic, Sharethrough etc, when the endpoint of smart is called from the new prebid adapter from publisher/ network end.

I want to know how to call bidders like YahooSSP, Sharethrough, Pubmatic etc through the new adapter in prebid that I am going to add soon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.